# List of OO languages where object immutability can be compiler enforced

Tags: language-agnostic, programming-languages, language-design, immutability

Can anyone give me a list of languages where class immutability can be compiler enforced and tested easily ?

I need to be able to do something like:

```
class immutable Person {
    private String name = "Jhon"; // lets say the String is mutable
    
    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name; // ok
    }

    public void setName(String newName) { 
        this.name = newName; // does not compile
    }

    public void getName() { 
        return this.name; //returns reference through which name can't be mutated
    }

    private void testImmutability() {
        getName().setFirstChar('a'); // does not compile
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

For a little more clarification, see [here](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4617197).

Comment: The more pressing question would be: Are there any? And why should `public void setName(...) { }` not compile? An empty function body doesn't mutate.

Comment: This should be a Community Wiki. And my entry: Scala.

Comment: @delnan agreed, lets assume there is code in the setName

Comment: @Joe I'd love if you could post an answer and give 2/3 lines example code :)

Comment: Could you tell more about "compiler enforced"?  If I define all data members in a C++ class as `const`, I can't change them after the initialization part of the constructor normally, but I could use a pointer to change things.  Is that OK?  (Disregard the possibility of casting for this question.)

Comment: @David no, you should not be able to change them at all, in your example the class is still mutable. I want the compiler to know when a class (or member) is immutable and not let me modify it in any way. Read the link in the question for more info. Generally if you can modify the class members in any way after object creation (be it pointers/subclassing/reflection etc.) its not immutable. This article might also help (if you haven't read it already) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object.

Comment: A little more clarification. From Wikipedia: Immutability does not imply that the object as stored in the computer's memory is unwriteable. Rather, immutability is a compile-time construct that indicates what a programmer should do, not necessarily what they can do (for instance, by circumventing the type system or violating const correctness in C or C++).

Comment: @Simeon:  Leaving me wondering exactly what you want.  Either the "can't change it at all" or "can't change it through legit means" definition is reasonable, but you seem to say different things in different comments.  In one of his books, Herb Sutter referred to "guarding against Murphy" and "guarding against Machiavelli".

Comment: @David I wan't the object to have mutable members AND not be changeble after initialization. new MyObj("name").getName() is ok, BUT newMyObj("name").getName().setChar1("1") shouldn't compile.

Answer (score 5):

Functional programming languages like OCAML, Haskell, and Erlang.

Comment: Thanks. Could you add some example code if you have some time ?

Comment: I hate to nit-pick but... technically, the OP asked for OO languages and Erlang in most definitely not an OO language. Also, Haskell is in sort of a gray array (i.e. it can do OO-like things, but doesn't have traditional OO constructs).

Comment: @pblasucci Point taken, but you don know we'd have to enter into the hairy topic of what is and not OO. OCAML has object concepts (the "O" added to CAML), Haskell has classes and inheritance, Erlang, I honestly don't know.

Comment: @Simeon Objects are immutable by default in the mentioned languages. Any code sample drawn from the Web will do.

Answer (score 4):

F# and Scala both have the ability to created compiler-enforced immutable types (i.e. classes).

The following shows the basics in F#...

```
// using records is the easiest approach (but there are others)
type Person = { Name:string; Age:int; }
let p = { Person.Name="Paul";Age=31; }

// the next line throws a compiler error
p.Name <- "Paulmichael"
```

Here's the equivalent Scala. Note that you can still make mutable objects by using `var` instead of `val`.

```
class Person(val name: String, val age: Int)
val p = new Person("Paul", 31)

// the next line throws a compiler error
p.name = "Paulmichael"
```

Comment: Can you give an example please :)

Answer (score 3):

[Joe-E](http://code.google.com/p/joe-e/)

From the [language spec](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~daw/joe-e/spec-20080203.pdf)

> ### 3.4 Immutable Types
>
> A type T is immutable if and only if it implements
>   the marker interface `org.joe_e.Immutable` according to the overlay
>   type system. The (empty) `org.joe_e.Immutable` interface must be provided
>   by the Joe-E implementation. The
>   intuition behind an immutable object
>   is that such an object cannot be
>   changed (mutated) in any observable
>   way, nor can any objects reachable by
>   following the elds of the immutable
>   object. The contents of an immutable
>   objects' elds and any objects
>   reachable from an immutable object
>   must not change once the object is
>   constructed. With the exception of
>   library classes explicitly deemed to
>   implement `Immutable`, an immutable
>   class must satisfy additional
>   linguistic restrictions enforced by
>   the verier (x4.4) to ensure this
>   property. Library classes that cannot
>   be automatically verified and are
>   deemed immutable must be carefully
>   manually veried to expose no
>   possibility for modication of their
>   contents. Note that immutability does
>   not place any restrictions on any
>   local variables dened within the
>   immutable class. It also says nothing
>   about the mutability of the arguments
>   passed to methods. It only applies to
>   the values stored in and objects
>   reachable from the immutable class's
>   elds

It also introduces useful notions of powerless, and selfless types.

Comment: Great :) This is what I'm looking for. This answer needs more votes IMHO.

Comment: @Simeon, a good resource for questions like this is http://www.eros-os.org/pipermail/cap-talk/ .  A lot of the people on that list work on secure/reliable software.  A lot at the OS/hardware level, but quite a few at the programming language level.

Comment: Conceptually, it should be considered perfectly proper for an immutable object to hold a reference to a mutable object, *if the reference encapsulates the identity rather than the state of the object in question*.  A common example of this pattern is the .net `Delegate` type.  A `Delegate` contains an immutable method pointer and an immutable reference to an object upon which that method should act, but in many cases the whole *purpose* of a delegate is to mutate its target.  That doesn't mean the delegate is mutable, however, since the target's state isn't part of the delegate's state.

Comment: @supercat, Yes.  Different languages go different ways depending on what they want from their immutable guarantees.  OCAML works similarly to C# via a `ref` type which underlies `mutable` class properties allowing them to do all kinds of useful reordering optimizations.  In the case of Joe-E, though, the guarantee that they're trying to preserve is that a method marked *pure* that has only immutable inputs is perfectly deterministic -- will have exactly the same result given the same inputs.  Treating immutable references to mutable cells as immutable would violate that determinacy guarantee.

Comment: @MikeSamuel: I'm not familiar with Joe-E, but I'm not quite sure I see the issue, provided that the methods are required to regard as opaque any references to mutable objects.  If one has a laminated tamper-resistant printed list of automotive Vehicle Identification Numbers, the list of cars would be immutable even though the cars themselves would not--nothing that happened to any of the cars would be regarded as affecting the list.  The big thing to recognize is which references should be regarded as encapsulating their targets and which ones should be regarded as merely identifying them.

Comment: @supercat, Sure.  You can make a shallowly immutable object frozen for the purpose of purity by preventing the pure fn from dereferencing any references it contains to mutable state.  Joe-E could have defined things this way, but they decided not to, probably for simplicity's sake -- Joe-E is defined as a verified subset of Java, so all dereferencing is implicit just as in Java.

Comment: @MikeSamuel: That makes sense.  One of my gripes with Java is that it does nothing to notate which references encapsulate objects and which ones identify them; such murkiness then makes it harder to guarantee anything without imposing tighter restrictions than would otherwise be necessary.  I think C++ was overcomplicated in some ways, and Java takes some good steps at simplifying it, but some missteps too.  Having a GC to allow immutable objects to be shared without tracking ownership is good, but *mutable objects should usually have clearly defined owners*.  Incidentally...

Comment: ...I would expect that allowing objects to be declared immutable could improve the performance of lightweight GC frameworks, since a gen-1 or gen-2 immutable object can be completely ignored during a gen-0 collection (since it's guaranteed not to hold any gen-0 references).  Taking full advantage of generational GC with mutable objects requires the use of write fences to detect when a gen-1 or gen-2 object may have had a gen-0 reference stored to it; lightweight frameworks can't afford that.  But multi-generation GC for immutable objects could be implemented more cheaply.

Comment: @supercat, Even when you have immutable objects, VM's often have mutable ones too so need a flexible memory management strategy.  One side-effect of Joe-E's definition of immutable is that they are necessarily acyclic which is easily collectible as you describe.  There is a verifiable definition of immutable that works for purity but which allows cyclic data by using a state-machine to guide the cyclic structure through unfrozen -> freezing -> immutable states and runtime guards to make sure that no unfrozen or freezing versions make it to pure functions.

Comment: @MikeSamuel: I think one could allow the creation of cyclic data structures that were verifiably immutable "from birth" by if one defined a "no-dereference/leak-safe" qualifier for classes, constructors, and storage locations.  Basically, the requirement would be that a "leak-safe" constructor not expose the object under construction except as a leak-safe argument to a leak-safe constructor or method whose return value would have to be regarded as leak-safe, and not do anything with leak-safe values except store them in leak-safe storage locations (in particular, not dereference them).

Comment: @MikeSamuel: I dislike popsicle immunity because an object may be observed to be in something other than its final state, and because it's generally not statically verifiable; with proper storage qualifiers, I think it should be possible to have a constructor  receive a reference to an object `Foo` which is under construction while making an enforceable promise that nothing would observe any aspect of `Foo`'s state until its construction was complete.

Comment: @MikeSamuel: As for VM's needing mutable objects as well as immutable ones, that is certainly true, but deterministic memory management is generally only a problem with immutable objects which can have many references but no clear "owner".  Generally, even when mutable objects have many references to them, one of them will be clearly regarded as the "owner".  The GC needs to track mutable objects well enough to ensure non-owning references don't get left pointing into space, but an object which is abandoned by its owner should be recognizable as such, even when other objects hold references.

Comment: @supercat, If deterministic memory management for immutable acyclic objects is the goal, then reference counting should suffice.  Reference counting is only worse than M&S when counting overhead is prohibitive (many references being copied about) or cycles prevent collection.

Comment: @MikeSamuel: Thread-safe reference counting is often expensive, and many types of immutable objects may contain cycles.

Answer (score 3):

The D (version D2) programming language has immutability. It has OOP, but immutability is rather a concept from functional pl. There it's called [purity](http://leonardo-m.livejournal.com/99194.html).